# How do I close InfoBubble? (google maps utility library v3)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm working with google maps utility library. More specifically with infoBubble, and I'm currently able to open an InfoBubble for a Marker, placed on my google map. What I want to know is how to attach an event to close that infoBubble. I'm struggling with this. Please help me.

Sincerely,

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        // Listen for user click on map to close any open info bubbles
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function () { 
          infoBubble.close();
        });
```

Comment: I switched to a different component, markerwithlabel because I was already behind. I think I tried the code you've posted here and I think it didn't work quite well. Does your code close an opened infoBubble by clicking on it?
Thank you for you help sir.

Comment: The "listener" is fired when the map is clicked anywhere. In effect only one infobubble will be open at one time. This works perfectly for me. 

The advantage of using InfoBubble over MarkerWithLabel is the ability to style the popup with more control. You can also create tabs within the popup which might not be possible with MarkerWithLabel.

Comment: Works great with InfoBubble.

Answer (score 0):

In the infobubble options simply write `hideCloseButton: false,`.
You will be able to see a close button on the right top corner of the infobubble
or add an event as DeeZone's answer has shown.